# need to install Windows on a Mac OS CPU

Tags: windows-7, mac

My friend wants to install Windows 7 on her Mac Mini.

Unfortunately, she does not own any original install CDs for Mac OS X, and a Google search suggests that the original install CD will be needed to proceed with the format.

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: That's a very large CPU, do you mean the case? If so, what model is it? You may be able to get Boot Camp working with a USB or network install.

Comment: @Phoshi: he probably meant the Mac Mini

Comment: yah, its the mac mini, just googled it

Comment: @phoshi Boot Camp..... never heard of that, i am not a Mac Guy

Comment: @mahen23: are you installing windows xp, vista or 7?

Comment: @mahen23: Tech dude, not Mac Guy, got it.

Comment: windows 7 @bcbck

Comment: Why would you need a Mac OS X CD to install Windows?

Answer (score 1):

Just boot from your windows media (hold down <kbd>c</kbd> while booting). It can then wipe the disk and install normally.

Comment: ok will try that next time